# Probability device components.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let there be two parts, $A$ and $B$, subject to random failures that form a device. The device fails if both parts are down. The two parts are not independent.
Given:
(1) a failure of part $A$ is equal to $0.2$;
(2) a failure of part $B$ is equal to $0.8$ if component $A$ is down;
(3) a failure of part $B$ is equal to $0.4$ if part $A$ is active.

Calculate the probability of a failure:
(i) of component $A$ if component $B$ is down;
(ii) of exactly one component.
(iii) A third part, $C$, is added to the device. The probability
that part $C$ breaks down is equal to $0.2$, independently of the state (up or down) of components $A$ and $B$. Given that the device is active, what is the probability that component $C4 is down?

My answers:
(i) $\Pr(A|B^c)=\frac{\Pr( A\cap B^c)}{Pr(A)} = \frac{Pr(B^c|A)\Pr(A)}{\Pr(B^c)}$
(ii) ???
(iii) $\Pr(C^c|A\cap B) = (1 - (\Pr(B^c)\Pr(A^c))(\Pr(C^c) $

Are these right?

Comment: I think your question i) and ii) are not worded correctly.

Comment: @jay You are right, I fixed it.

Comment: why are you caluclating $Pr(B)$ for (i)? In general your answer attempts don't match the questions for i) and ii).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem (i):** Let $A,B$ respectively be the events that A, B are working. For (i), we want are asked for $\Pr(A^c|B^c)$.  We could get this from $\Pr(A|B^c)$, so in principle we could use your procedure. But the formula you end up with is not correct.

I prefer to go back to the definition of conditional probability, rather than trying for some version of Bayes' Formula. This is for the practical reason that students tend to make more mistakes when using Bayes' Formula.

Recall that 
$$\Pr(A^c|B^c)=\frac{\Pr(A^c\cap B^c)}{\Pr(B^c)}.$$
We want to evaluate the two probabilities on the right.

The component B can be down in two ways: A is OK, but B is down **or** A is down and B is down. The probability A is OK and B is down is $(0.8)(0.4)$. The probability A is down and B is down is $(0.2)(0.8)$. Add. That gets us $\Pr(B^c)$. And as a bonus, during the calculation we observed that $\Pr(A^c\cap B^c)=(0.2)(0.8)$, so now we know everything.

**Problem (ii):** We want $\Pr(A\cap B^c)+\Pr(A^c\cap B)$. But recycling is a virtue. Note that our probability is $1-\left(\Pr(A\cap B)+\Pr(A^c\cap B^c)\right)$, and we have already computed $\Pr(A^c\cap B^c)$.

So all we need is $\Pr(A\cap B)$. The probability that A is OK is $0.8$. We were essentially told that if A is OK, then B is OK with probability $0.6$. So $\Pr(A\cap B)=(0.8)(0.6)$.

For practice, or as a check, you may want to compute $\Pr(A\cap B^c)$ and $\Pr(A^c\cap B)$.

**Problem (iii):** We do want $\Pr(C^c|A\cup B)$. For compute this, we could use the conditional probability formula. Maybe you should do that, calculating $\Pr(A\cup B)$ and $\Pr(C\cap(A\cup B))$. But then think about the answer.